# How to grab value of custom tag and value between tag

Tags: php, regex, arrays

The idea is to grab values from the following string.

```
String: Server has [cpu]4[cpu] cores and [ram]16gb[ram]
```

I need to grab the tags value and what is between the tag dynamically: should not matter what is between `[*]*[*]`

Output: Should be an array as follows

```
Array(
    'cpu' => 4,
    'ram' => '16gb'
)
```

Having a lot of trouble with the regex pattern. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: the value between tags or the tags themselves can be anything - Alphanumeric or Numeric.

The sample string is a sample only. Tags can appear unlimited times and the array therefore needs to be populated on the fly - not manually.

Comment: Is it `[tag][tag]` or `[tag][/tag]`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar [tag][tag] is preferred but can be [tag][/tag]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My PHP is rusty, but maybe:

```
$str = "Server has [cpu]4[cpu] cores and [ram]16gb[ram] and [memory]2tb[/memory]";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\[(\w+)\]([^\[\]]+)\[\/?\w+\]/', $str, $matches);
$output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Details:

- Anything but a `[` or `]` can appear in `[]` as the tag.
- Anything but a `[` or `]` can be the value of the tag
- The closing tag doesn't need to match the starting tag. You could use a backreference, but then it would be case sensitive.

Comment: `+1` Works perfectly! Superb! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '[cpu]4[cpu] cores and [ram]16gb[ram]';

preg_match('|\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[/?[^\]]+\][^\[]+\[([^\]]+)\]([^\[]+)\[/?[^\]]+\]|', $string, $matches);
$array = array($matches[1] => $matches[2], $matches[3] => $matches[4]);

print_r($array);
```

Comment: This will allow / in tags as well btw.

Comment: This works only for `[tag]int[tag] some text [tag]string[tag]`! Not a complete solution, whcih gives tag value pair

Comment: It matches the example string provided. I assume the OP is only expecting a digit in the first field and a alphanumeric in the second.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. This outputs '16gb', seems to ignore the first match. Also needs to grab the tag itself. See above under Output in my question. Thanks again

Comment: the value can be numeric/alphanumeric - should not matter.

Comment: use new version its more relaxing on what it accepts. Tested and workes.

Comment: Hi @cryptic, sorry for the early accepting. I should make myself a little bit more clear. This needs to be dynamic, as in: The string can be anything and the tags can appear numerous times. So you could have 4 tags in a string. Your solution is fine for the current string only.

Comment: ah ok, gimme a few mins to whip up something.

Answer (score 1):

#### Working Code, slightly modified version of [walkerneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828584/walkerneo):

Others can build upon my code or suggest me in doing something better:

```
<pre><?php
    $string = "Server has [cpu]4[cpu] cores and [ram]16gb[ram] and [memory]2tb[/memory]";
    $matches = array();
    $pattern = '/\[(\w+)\]([^\[\]]+)\[\/?\w+\]/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    $output = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    var_dump($output);
?></pre>
```

#### Fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/n1i-e1p

Comment: This won't work, you did not escape any of the brackets, they are being interpreted as character classes and will not match anything but ( . and *

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Populates an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

If allowed to use multiple preg_match, this may be a solution:

```
    $str = '[cpu]4[cpu] cores and [ram]16gb[ram][hdd]1TB[hdd]asdaddtgg[vga]2gb[vga]';
    $arrResult = array();
    preg_match_all('/(\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\][A-Za-z0-9]+\[[A-Za-z0-9]+\])/i', $str, $match,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if (is_array($match)) {
        foreach ($match as $tmp) {
            if (preg_match('/\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]([A-Za-z0-9]+)\[([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]/', $tmp[0], $matchkey)) {
                $arrResult[$matchkey[1]] = $matchkey[2];
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($arrResult);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  'cpu' =>
  string(1) "4"
  'ram' =>
  string(4) "16gb"
  'hdd' =>
  string(3) "1TB"
  'vga' =>
  string(3) "2gb"
}
```